# A constructor function, the object of which hides/shows an html element

Tags: javascript

I need to write a constructor function the object of which hides/shows an html element, and then I need an inheritor object than does the same but smoothly. Here is what I could write so far, but something is not working, any help?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    <h3 style = "cursor: pointer;" onclick = "toggleDiv.toggle()">Click to toggle</h3>
    <p id = "toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <h3 style = "cursor: pointer;" onclick = "sToggleDiv.sToggle()">Click to toggle smoothly</h3>
    <p id = "smooth">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <script>

    var simpleToggler = {
        Toggler : function(id){
            this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
            this.toggle = function(){
                if(this.elem.style.display == 'none'){
                    this.elem.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    this.elem.style.display = 'none'; 
                }
            }
        }

    };

    var smoothToggler = {
        Toggler : function(){
            setTimeout(this.toggle, 500);
        }

    };

    smoothToggler.prototype = simpleToggler;

        var toggleDiv = new simpleToggler.Toggler('toggle');
        toggleDiv.toggle();
        var sToggleDiv = new smoothToggler.Toggler('smooth');
        sToggleDiv.toggle();


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your smooth toggle's click event seem to be wrong.

it should be

```
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="sToggleDiv.toggle()">Click to toggle smoothly</h3>
```

Also your prototype definition should be as follows

```
smoothToggler.Toggler.prototype = new simpleToggler.Toggler('smooth');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are misunderstandings about inheritance here:

- The prototype needs to be set on the constructor function, not a containing object. `smoothToggler.Toggler.prototype = simpleToggler.Toggler.prototype;` would probably do what you are expecting.
- Any methods defined in the constructor are not part of the prototype and won't be inherited. Instead of defining `this.toggle` inside the constructor function, define it as `simpleToggler.Toggler.prototype.toggle` outside the constructor.
- When you call `new smoothToggler.Toggler('smooth');`, the 'smooth' argument is ignored. `sToggleDiv` will have no `elem` property. You need to handle that in the smoothToggler constructor.

I also don't think you really want to do `setTimeout` within the constructor. It would make more sense to do that within the `toggle` method. Try something like this:

```
var simpleToggler = {}, smoothToggler = {};
(function () {
    function toggle(elem){
        if(elem.style.display == 'none'){
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            elem.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    }
    function init(o, id) { o.elem = document.getElementById(id); }
    simpleToggler.Toggler = function (id) { init(this, id); };
    simpleToggler.Toggler.prototype.toggle = function () {
        toggle(this.elem);
    };
    smoothToggler.Toggler = function (id) { init(this, id); };
    smoothToggler.Toggler.prototype.toggle = function () {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {toggle(that.elem);}, 500);
    };
})();
```

You also need to change one of the click events: "sToggleDiv.sToggle()" to "sToggleDiv.toggle()".